# CakePHP, NOT IN or excluding JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, cakephp-1.3

the tables are:

```
units (id,...)   // approx' 10,000 units
contracts(id, unit_id, active, ...) // approx 50,000 records
```

I want to get all the units, that have no contract attached to them (and `contracts.active=true`).

My ideas are:
Using `NOT IN`:
    select * from units
    where id NOT IN(select unit_id from contracts where contracts.active = true)
Or:

```
select * from units u
left join contracts c
on c.unit_id = u.id
where c.unit_id is null
```

and, if there is a native way to do it in cake, please show me the light :)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your other joins are, the NOT IN could give you bad performance. I would suggest the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM units AS u
LEFT JOIN contracts AS c
ON (c.unit_id = u.id AND c.active = 1)
WHERE c.id IS NULL
```

According to the [cakephp documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#complex-find-conditions):

> Cake can also check for null fields. In this example, the query will return records where the post title is not null:

```
array ("NOT" => array (
        "Post.title" => null
    )
)
```

So depending on how your models are setup, this may work for you:

```
$joins = array(('table' => 'contracts',
                'alias' => 'Contracts',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array('Contracts.active' => 0)));
$conditions = array('Contracts.id' => NULL);
$units = $this->Units->find('all', array('joins' => $joins, 'conditions' => $conditions));
```